# Iterating over an ArrayList adding values

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, floating-point, iteration

[image]
Is it possible to iterate over a ArrayList adding not all instances but every 12? There are many threads on using addAll to add all instances but not sections.

I currently have an ArrayList containing hundreds of float values:

Snippet:

`120.5, 22.2, 76.2, 64.5, 38.3, 27.1, 149.4, 62.3, 127.9, 79.1, 83.4, 68.3, 61.0, 83.4, 5.4, 83.8, 78.3, 111.8, 104.1, 145.2, 94.3, 20.0, 104.7, 35.9, 68.6, 10.1, 41.1, 82.2, 170.7, 17.2, 122.1, 61.0, 46.3, 101.1, 59.0, 30.0, ...`

What I want to do is sum the first 12 instances and put this total in a new ArrayList, sum the next 12 instances, store this into the newly created ArrayList and so on. There are exactly 996 instances so i should have 83 new values in this new ArrayList (996/12=83).

Can this be done? If so how? Here is where I have got to...

```
  // ArrayList that contains the float values shown above

  public MonthData depthValues() {
    ArrayList<Float> rValue = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<months.size(); i++)
    {
        rValue.add(months.get(i).getDepthMM());
    }
    System.out.println(rValue);
    System.out.println(rValue.size());
    return null;

  }

  //New arrayList im trying to make
  //probably done this wrong, help needed here

  public MonthData depthTotals() {
    ArrayList<Float> depthAdd = new ArrayList<Float>();

  int t = 12;

  for(int i = 0; i<rValue.size(); ++i)
  {
    ??????????????????
  }
  }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated I cant seem to find anything on this anywhere as I think the sum of all instances is such a popular topic. Its probably a case of iterating properly. In regards to the summing I would have use `accumulate` in c++, but do not know the equivalent of this in java (if there is one). Thank you for any advice/assistance in advance!

MORE CODE:

```
public class WeatherStation {
  private ArrayList<MonthData> months;
  private ArrayList<MonthData> rValue;
  private ArrayList<MonthData> depthAdd;
```

MonthData is a model for data being read to this class it consists on a lot of getters....

```
public class MonthData {

  int y;
  int m;
  float h;
  ...


  public MonthData(String data) throws Exception {
    ...
    this.parseData(data);
  }


  void parseData(String csvData) {
    String[] parseResult = csvData.trim().split("\\s+");

    this.setYear(parseResult[0]);
    this.setMonth(parseResult[1]);
    ...


  public String toString() {
    return "y =" + year + ", m =" + month + ",...

  }


  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  // followed by lots of getters for: m, h, c, f, r, s, ... 




   public MonthData depthValues() {
    ArrayList<Float> rValue = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<months.size(); i++)
{
    rValue.add(months.get(i).getDepthMM());
}
System.out.println(rValue);
System.out.println(rValue.size());
return null;
```

}

Code recommended:

```
 public MonthData depthTotals() {
    ArrayList<Float> depthAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Float> it = rValue.iterator();
    final int MAX = 12;
    while (it.hasNext()){
      float sum = 0f;
      int counter = 1;
      //iterating 12 times
      //still check if there is an element in list
      while (counter < MAX && it.hasNext()){
        sum += it.next();
        counter++;
      }
      depthAdd.add(sum);}
    }
```

ISSUE: `Iterator<Float> it = rValue.iterator();`

Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Iterator<MonthData>` to `Iterator<Float>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is using `Iterator` and a counter of `12` by using a `while`. Here's an example:

```
List<Float> yourList = ...;
// fill yourList
List<Float> results = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Float> it = yourList.iterator();
final int MAX = 12;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    float sum = 0f;
    int counter = 1;
    //iterating 12 times
    //still, check if there's an element in your list
    while (counter <= MAX && it.hasNext()) {
        sum += it.next();
        counter++;
    }
    result.add(sum);
}
```

Comment: `counter <= MAX` should be the condition as you are starting the counter with `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I do however have an issue regarding:
`Iterator<Float> it = rValue.iterator();`

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<MonthData> to Iterator<Float>

Comment: @Abbie what's that issue? Could you provide more code in your question after editing it to provide proper help?

Comment: @Abbie from your new code, you have defined `ArrayList<MonthData> rValue` and in your previous code you were using `ArrayList<Float> rValue`. In case you're using the former, then change your iterator to `Iterator<MonthData> it` and instead of doing `sum += it.next()` use `sum += it.next().<nameOfYourGetter>();`.

Comment: Ive added a picture for you. Think were getting mixed up here, rValue is a `<Float>` hence why i dont understand the error im getting :(

Comment: Well, I'm seeing this: `private ArrayList<MonthData> rValue;` inside `WeatherStation` class.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you use `double` or `Double` instead of float as it has around half a trillion times the accuracy.

You can sum every block of 12 like this

```
public static List<Double> sumBlocks(List<Double> list, int blockSize) {
    List<Double> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += blockSize) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0, len = Math.min(list.size() - i, blockSize); j < len; j++)
            sum += list.get(i + j);
        ret.add(sum);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and call

```
List<Double> sums = sumBlocks(list, 12);
```

Comment: `Math.min` with one argument?

Comment: You cannot use `double` or any primitive types with generics, it has to be Object Type.

Comment: @abhishekbafna indeed but there are libraries with collections which support primitives. koloboke, trove, gs-collections etc. http://java-performance.info/large-hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove/

Comment: @abhishekbafna He's not using `double` with generics.  I don't see the problem.  (If you're talking about `sum`, this is legal; Java will automatically convert between `Double` and `double` when necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate yet another way to accomplish this:

```
public static List<Double> sumBlocks(List<Double> list, int blockSize) {
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
    double sum = 0d;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i % blockSize == 0) {
            result.add(sum);
            sum = 0d;
        }
        sum += list.get(i);
    }
    result.add(sum);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arraylist objects inherit the sublist(start, end) method from the List class. You can use myList.sublist(i, j) to access the sublist and get your sum. From there, it should be just simple arithmetic to get your iteration. Inside your for-loop, it should be: myList.sublist(i*12, i*12 + 12).

```
//Input list
ArrayList<Float> inputList = new ArrayList<Float>();

ArrayList<Float> result = new ArrayList<Float>();
    int groupSize = 12;
    int offset=0;
    while(offset < inputList.size()) {
        int toIndex = (inputList.size()-offset)>=groupSize? offset+groupSize : inputList.size();
        result.add( listSum(inputList.subList(offset,  toIndex)) );
        offset += groupSize;
    }
```

Helper method to add items in a list

```
static float listSum(List<Float> ar) {
    float accumulator = 0f;
    for(float item:ar) {
        accumulator += item;
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lista<Double> list = // original list
List<Double> ret = new ArrayList<>();

int counter = 0;
double sum = 0; 

for (Double f : list) {
   if (counter == 12) {
       sum = 0;
       counter = 0;
       ret.add(sum);
   }
   sum += f;
   counter++;
}
// if list is not a multiple of 12
if (list.size() % 12 != 0) {
    ret.add(sum);
}
return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public float total;

for(int i; i < rValue.Size(); i ++)
{
     total += rValue[i];

if(i%12=0)
  {
     add total to new ArrayList
     total = 0;
  }
}
```